# How to find the integration of $\sin2\theta\sqrt{\tan\theta} \ d\theta$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to find the area between the line with slope $=.5$ and a circle with center $(5,5)$ and radius $=5$ but using the polar integration I changed the circle equation to polar form you can see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piC7V.jpg)

I had difficulty integrating both
$$\int\sin2\theta\sqrt{\tan\theta} \  d\theta$$

And

$$\int\sin2\theta\sqrt{cot\theta} \ d\theta$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Refer to this for a basic tutorial on MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Writing everything in $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ and then substituting $u=\cos \theta$ and simplifying should help you.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \sin 2\theta \sqrt{\tan \theta}d\theta=4\int \frac{t^4}{1+t^4}dt $$ where $t^2=\tan \theta$